# Star schema dimension table design

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, star-schema

In a star schema, can a dimension table such as customer_dim have a column that references another dimension?

For example:

#### customer_dim

```
customer_id
first_name
last_name
email
primary_billing_address_dim
```

Comment: What is the context of the question?  Is this an academic question about the difference between a pure star schema and a snowflake schema?  A practical question of whether it makes sense to model the data this way as opposed to putting the address information into the customer dimension?  Something else?

Answer (score 2):

When dimensions have references to other dimensions, we call that a Snow Flake instead of a Star schema. Depending on how you query your model later on, one approach might be more efficient than the other. It is possible to transform a Snow Flake in a Star Schema by flattening everything in the dimension linked to the fact table(s) – customer_dim in your example.

Some tools (like Microstrategy) behaves very well with a Snow Flake model. On the contrary Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition will require you to model your business model as a star schema.

For ad-hoc query performance, both approach should be benchmarked. A pure star schema reduces the number of joins so it might be faster. In term of data quality and master data management, the snow flake is probably easier to handle.